# I have coded a program in C# but all in the form how do I get all of the code to work in classes rather than forms?

Tags: c#

As the title says I have made a small program in C# which I did no realise needed to be in classes not forms because now I cannot run tests on the code so how do I move the code from a form into a class without losing the functionality and how do I pass values from text boxes from the class to the form

Comment: This is *far* too broad.  In general, you compose the functionality into objects and your UI code uses those objects.  I can't really be more specific without actual examples, though.

Comment: you simply create a new class and you paste in the code. simples! to pass in values to your methods, you call it with the parameter you want to pass

Comment: Copy-Paste them into classes and use those classes? I'd recommend MVC architecture, but I have a feeling you're not there yet.

Comment: Like @Ahmedilyas, do that. THEN if you come across any errors or problems that you haven't been able to fix yourself, then consider asking a question on StackOverflow (assuming you first check if the question already exists or not).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's say you wanted all the event code to exist in a *controller*. You'd build a class:

```
public class FormController
{
    public void SomeButtonClicked(parms) { }
}
```

and move the code in there. Now, this is way to broad to provide fine grained guidance because some of the code probably belongs in other classes (i.e. database work).

Now, in the constructor of the `Form`, store an instance of this controller:

```
_controller = new FormController();
```

and then in the click of a button (for example):

```
_controller.SomeButtonClicked(...);
```

Here, `_controller` is a private variable on the `Form`. Further, each form would need its own controller.